# Make a method on an array of Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, `Report` and I'd like to create a method `users` such that I can call `@reports.users` and get a list of all users for all reports in the array.  Where do I write the function definition?

Comment: here `app/models/report.rb`

Comment: Do you really need a method? Couldn't you just go `@reports.collect{|r| r.users}.flatten` ?

Comment: micapam, your solution works elegantly.  Feel free to submit it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you need to add static method in your reports model. Its better if you name your method some thing other than 'users' because if you have association like this

```
has_many :users
```

it will cause couple of errors or may be anonymous behaviors.

```
def self.get_all_users
  all_users = collect{|report| report.users}
  all_users.flatten!
end
```

now

```
@reports.get_all_users
```

will return all users

Answer (score 0):

I think you need relationship to call that function
In Your reports model,
add these

```
belongs_to :user
```

In Your user model
add

```
has_many :reports
```

Make sure your report model has user_id field.
Then you can call
@report.users from your report controller.
like this in your report controller index method

```
@reports = Report.users
```